# What are these queries my router seems to be making?

Tags: router, logging

[image: screenshot]

I am logging my home router's firewall. It gives a lot of entries like these:

```
 07:17:00.157793 IP 192.168.178.1.serialgateway > 192.168.178.10.syslog: SYSLOG local0.alert, length: 136
 07:17:00.755564 IP 192.168.178.1.isbconference1 > 192.168.178.10.syslog: SYSLOG local0.alert, length: 136
 07:17:00.918577 IP 192.168.178.1.isbconference2 > 192.168.178.10.syslog: SYSLOG local0.alert, length: 136
 07:17:02.746611 IP 192.168.178.1.payrouter > 192.168.178.10.syslog: SYSLOG local0.alert, length: 136
```

192.168.178.1 is my router. It seems unlikely my router would make these queries by itself. How do I find out where it is coming from and (what) should I do something about it?

Comment: You configure your router to send syslog messages to 192.168.178.10 and then you think that your router would not be sending things to 192.168.178.10 by itself? This makes no sense. What I think you are looking for is to understand what the different fields are in the log. From your comment below, `serialgateway` is the source port that the router is sending syslog messages from. This makes this not a security question, but simply a TCP basics question.

Comment: why does `serialgateway` change 1000's of times as if it is running through a dictionary? it seems to be querying the source port from a dictionary to my PC, that's my question then

Comment: Again, this is purely a TCP basics question. Source ports are random. Please look up "TCP source port" on Google. And look at the log. Don't just freak out. Look at each field and see what it is telling you. Your router is connecting to your syslog server. There is no "querying" of anything. And all those 1000's of things are on your router's side, not your PC's side.

Comment: you mean they are named? I thought only numbered

Comment: Many ports have common services that run on them, so whatever is generating the log is replacing the number with the common service on that port.

Comment: there are over 10.000 different names over last night

Comment: I'm not going to try and walk you through TCP/IP basics. Of course there were 10,000 different service names. That's not unusual at all.

Comment: what makes you say I freak out?

Comment: I knew it was my router making the entries but I have only heard of numbered ports. I'm inferring from your answer that these are either services running on my router (probably not what you mean) or somewhere on the internet. Is that correct? Do you have a link? I was actually logging because I saw an outgoing SMTP ALLOW'ed logged somewhere that I didn't recognise (176.9.92.102).

Comment: You are not understanding the facts so you are assuming the worst instead of systematically understanding what you are seeing. So much so, you posted on an information security site. You assumed "querying", dictionary attacks", and that 10,000 entries is relevant. These are an overraction (a freak out).

Comment: Please, please, just google TCP/IP source ports as I have said from the beginning.

Comment: dude I am as calm as the pacific, I was digging through some material about DNS /etc/hosts being ignored by Tor browser which is outdated or not for Mac, so I saw there are a lot of Q&A here and joined this website

Comment: one can be calm and still overreact

Comment: That's fine. You asked a non-security question on a security site, that's all.

Comment: I see, you're right. I freaked out and need to take a break. Would you know if Tor browser ignores /etc/hosts and if third party scripts generally (in Safari) ignores /etc/hosts? And if 176.9.92.102 is protonmail?

Comment: No offense Schroeder, but this [link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/building-internet-firewalls/1565928717/ch04.html) says: The TCP source port
    A two-byte number that specifies what client or server process the packet is coming from on the source machine. So I'd expect mostly numbers in that log, but it's mostly names, apparently service names.

Comment: and I explained that part

Comment: "whatever is generating the log is replacing the number with the common service on that port" right? considering it's a firewall log, this seemed like a good website to post this question, so it's randomizing the port number and replacing the number with a name if there is a (named) service that's commonly using that port

Comment: "It" is not randomising the port number. When TCP connections are made, the process that wants to connect picks a random port to run on every time. In this case, the syslog service. It's that random port number that is being logged. Sometimes, there are common services that are associated with those ports, and that port number/service pair is stored in a database. Whenever generated the log you posted used such a database to translate the number to the service. Just like it did for `syslog` on your PC side. None of this is about firewalls or security. This is TCP/IP.

Comment: port number/service pair is stored in a database, used such a database, right

Answer (score 1):

Your router is sending these packets itself. They contain log messages. The syslog protocol is generally used to record the logs from several devices on a central server.

Your router has been configured to send log messages to 192.168.178.10. You should find a page somewhere in the router's web UI to allow you to change the address or disable syslog entirely.

.serialgateway, .payrouter, .isbconference1, .isbconference2, etc. is the name of the source port. Usually source port numbers are chosen randomly (only the destination port really matters). The program you are using to capture the data is looking up which protocol normally uses those ports and displaying that instead of the number. Apparently the "random" ports your router is sending packets from, are the ports typically used by some other protocols. There is no security problem with that.

Comment: what are the .payrouter, .isbconference1, .isbconerence 2, (1000's of these) etc. ? It looks like something is running a dictionary on my router or something (I enabled this logging myself)

Comment: @JuliusBaer I updated the answer.